# Get a Request Attribute with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, request

I have the following code in my servlet class:

```
request.setAttribute("myValueName", myValue); //Note: myValue is a TreeMap
```

I want to access this attribute via jQuery. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var myNewVariable = ???;
```

Note that this attribute is NOT in the URL of the page.

Comment: What is `request` in this case? Servlet classes and TreeMaps are not common terms in JavaScript / jQuery. Is there something else at work here?

Comment: It's a Java `HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score -2):

Servlet code

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
request.setAttribute("myValueName", "myValue");
request.getRequestDispatcher("URL for redirecting page").forward(request, response);
```

Example URL ="/WEB-INF/Project/Update.jsp"

In jQquery

```
var myNewVariable = "${myValueName}";
alert(myNewVariable);
```

Comment: Please check up on how to format code in questions and answers.

Comment: False, doesn't work.